# Override Doctrine constraint UniqueConstraint

Tags: symfony, symfony5, sylius

I'm working on a project where I'm using Sylius. I have to override a default constraint related to the `ChannelPricing` entity.

Here is the original constraint declaration:
The link to the original file :
https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/v1.10.7/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/model/ChannelPricing.orm.xml

```xml
    <mapped-superclass name="Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ChannelPricing" table="sylius_channel_pricing">
        <unique-constraints>
            <unique-constraint columns="product_variant_id,channel_code" name="product_variant_channel_idx" />
        </unique-constraints>
    </mapped-superclass>
```

I was able to create a migration with my new constraint when I use the annotation `@UniqueEntity` on the extended entity class:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="sylius_channel_pricing",
 *     uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(
 *     name="product_variant_channel_customer_group_idx",
 *     columns={"product_variant_id", "channel_code", "customerGroup_id"})},
 * )
 */
class ChannelPricing extends BaseChannelPricing
```

But... these lines only generates a migration to create the constraint `product_variant_channel_customer_group_idx`.. I want to tell Doctrine that I want to drop the default constraint `product_variant_channel_idx` first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was to defined a new name for the constraint.
If I use the original, Doctrine understand that I want to make an override and generate the drop instruction.

So, for these annotations :

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="sylius_channel_pricing",
 *     uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(
 *     name="product_variant_channel_idx",
 *     columns={"product_variant_id", "channel_code", "customerGroup_id"})},
 * )
 */
class ChannelPricing extends BaseChannelPricing
{
```

The generated migration :

```php
public function up(Schema $schema): void
{
    // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
    $this->addSql('DROP INDEX product_variant_channel_idx ON sylius_channel_pricing');
    $this->addSql('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX product_variant_channel_idx ON sylius_channel_pricing (product_variant_id, channel_code, customerGroup_id)');
}
```